# node.js sorting array by category and rendering it (slicing)

Tags: node.js

i'm learning node and i have done sorting by category and rendering it, but my plan is to slice articles. Each category should render only 3 of its array. I just dont have idea how to do it, i ended up in a loop trying to solve it hah.

My code in app.js (because its a home page)

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  Category.find({}, function(err, category) {
    Article.find({}, function(err, articles) { 
      res.render("index", { categories: category, articles: articles});
    });
  });
});
```

And my index.hbs (handlebars)

```
{{#each categories}}
    <div class="category">
        <a href="/category/{{this._id}}">{{this.title}}</a>
    </div> 
    {{#each ../articles}}
        {{#ifEquals ../this.title   this.category}}
            <div>{{this.title}}</div>   
        {{/ifEquals}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I have registered helper slice, and it works when i use it like this

```
{{#slice articles limit="3"}}
<div>{{this.title}}</div>
{{/slice}}
```

But as said, i would like to render just 3 articles of each category, but i have no idea how :/

Answer (score 0):

Then it seems that the issue is that you haven't restricted the `Article.find` to return only `articles` of `category` so for every category all the articles are being returned so the result is the same 3 articles for each category. The query `{}` on `Article.find` needs to have `category` in it.

---

If `articles` is an Array then you could take its slice before passing it to render you can do:

```
articles = articles.slice(0, 3);
```

This results in the first 3 articles. Those at indexes 0, 1, and 2.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  Category.find({}, function(err, category) {
    Article.find({}, function(err, articles) {
      articles = articles.slice(0, 3); 
      res.render("index", { categories: category, articles: articles});
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes i understand that, that gives the same result as the slice helper i posted above. But I want to slice articles of each category

For example
Category sport
3 articles of sport

Comment: Then it seems that the issue is that you haven't restricted the `Article.find` to return only `articles` of `category` so for every category all the articles are being returned so the result is the same 3 articles for each category.

Comment: I also understand that, but what is problem is I dont know how to sort them and render them, then i would use slice helper in handlebars to show. I imagine that the code for that should look like 

if category === article.category 
articles[category] = article

and in render articles[i], but what i? how should i call it

Comment: When i set Article.find({"category": category.title}, function(err, articles)
it doesnt work, and i dont know why.

But when I do it like     for(i = 0; i < category.length; i++)
    {
      Article.find({"category": category[i].title}, function(err, articles) {
        if(err) { console.log(err); } 
        console.log(articles.slice(0, 3));
        //res.render("index", { categories: category, articles: articles});
      });  
    }
it does the thing but I dont know how to render it, how to pass array